# React Typescript how to type props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

I have a simple react component.

```
interface iRowData{
   name: string
}

export default function ResultsSection(data: iRowData[]) {
   return <div>Results</div>
}
```

I get an error when I use this in another component.

```
export default function NewPage(){
   const rowData:iRowData[] = []
   return <ResultsSection data={rowData} />
}
```

The word data is highlighted red, and this is the error I keep getting.

```
Type '{ data: iRowData[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & iRowData[]'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & iRowData[]'.ts(2322)
(property) data: iRowData[]
```

Comment: Components take an OBJECT as their parameter (yes, an array is an object but you know what I mean). `{ data }: { data: iResults[] }`

Comment: Its because he is saying that data (which would be props) is of type name: string. needs to be destructured as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to unpack the incoming parameters, e.g.

```
interface iResults {
   name: string;
}

interface ResultSectionProps {
   data: iResults[];
}

export default function ResultsSection({ data }: ResultSectionProps) {
   return <div>Results</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props in as an object:

```
export default function ResultsSection({ data }: { data: iResults[] }) {
  return <div>Results</div>;
}

export default function NewPage() {
  const rowData: iRowData[] = [];
  return <ResultsSection data={rowData} />;
}
```

Notice that ResultsSection now takes an object with property `data: iResults[]`, rather than taking a single parameter of that type.

I also notice that you're using two different types; `iRowData` and `iResults`. Is this intentional? Is there any overlap between these two types? If they are completely different, you'll still get a different error.

Comment: @kelsny good spot, fixed

Comment: You're right.  I just fixed it.  They're all iRowData.